# Постоянная смена картинки при нажатии на JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку, картинка меняется лишь один раз:

```
<img src='img/images.png' onclick='this.src="img/images1.png"'>
```

Как в `onclick='this.src=*` менять адрес на следующее изображение?

Comment: Что у вас уже получилось?

Comment: нужно на разные картинки менять?

Comment: Ну раз _менять_, то конечно, нужно на разные! На одну и ту же, менять не получится чисто логически.

Comment: @yar85 Да, именно на разные. Суть в том, что нужно сделать постоянную замену "как бы зациклить". (если что, не судить строго, начинающий кодер)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const IMAGE_SOURCES = [
  'https://picsum.photos/300/180?image=11', 
  'https://picsum.photos/300/180?image=12', 
  'https://picsum.photos/300/180?image=15', 
  'https://picsum.photos/300/180?image=18', 
  'https://picsum.photos/300/180?image=19'
]; 

var srcGen = imageSrcGenerator(IMAGE_SOURCES), 
    imgEl  = document.getElementById('pic'); 
imgEl.addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.src = srcGen.next().value; 
}); 
imgEl.click(); 

function* imageSrcGenerator(srcArr) {
  let i = -1;
  while (++i < srcArr.length || !(i = 0))
    yield srcArr[i]; 
}
```

```html
<img id="pic">
```

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту проблему без JS, на нативном CSS:

```css
.accordion-header a:target, 
.accordion-header a:last-child {
 display: block;
}
.accordion-header a,
.accordion-header a:target ~ a:last-child {
 display: none
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-header">
 <a id="i1" href="#i2">
  <img src="https://1000.tech/img/bg0.jpg">
 </a>
 <a id="i2" href="#i1">
  <img src="https://1000.tech/img/pages/godlike/godlike.css.jpg">   
 </a>
</div>
```